# Understanding $\operatorname{argmin}$ in the given expression

Tags: matrices, vectors, normal-distribution, signal-processing

Let $B(m) \in \{-1,1\}$ be the transmitted symbols, for $m=1,2,\dots,1000$. Based on $B(m) = \pm 1$,

$$\begin{aligned} \psi_{m,0} &= h_m-\alpha f_mg_m \\ \psi_{m,1} &= h_m+\alpha f_mg_m \end{aligned}$$

where $\alpha = 0.5$, $h, f$ and $g$ are complex Gaussian random variables with zero mean and unit variance. Then,

$$ \tilde{s_m(n)} = \underset{s_m(n) \in \mathcal{A}_s}{\operatorname{argmin}} \left| \frac{\psi_{m,0}^H}{\| \psi_{m,0}^H \|^2}-s_m(n) \right|^2 $$

where $s_m(n)$ is [quadrature phase shift keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying) (QPSK) modulated signal, $\mathcal{A}_s$ is modulation alphabet set and $n = 1,2,\dots, 256$. What does $\operatorname{argmin}$ indicate in above expression?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The argmin is the "argument of the minimum," i.e. the thing for which the minimum is attained.

Comment: Thank u so much sir for ur reply....could u pls tell in more specific manner with respect to this given expression...

Comment: I don't know what else you want - the argmin of $f(x)$ is the $x$ that minimizes the value of $f(x).$ So you minimize your object in question and  find what input achieves the minimum.

Comment: Ok sir...So can we say that here in the given expression for which $s_m(n)$ the function is minimized.

Comment: I am getting confused due to presence of $m$ and $n$ in the expression....

Answer (score 1):

For $y = \underset{x} {\operatorname{argmin}} f(x)$, the value of $y$ is the value of $x$ at which the function $f(x)$ attains its minimum. For example,

$$
y = \underset{x} {\operatorname{argmin}} \, (x - 4)^2 = 4,
$$

since $x = 4$ is where $(x-4)^2$ attains its minimum value.

Comment: Thank u sir for ur reply....but can u pls tell me in the context of equation that I had written....

Comment: @Heretolearn Look at what you wrote below $\operatorname{argmin}$